# How do I get my network adaptor back? Claims unplugged when plugged in, and says "safe to remove" when I unplug the cable

Tags: windows-xp, networking

My system:

- Windows XP, SP3
- HP 6730b laptop

Here are the symptoms:

- Neither the orange nor the green LED flash when I insert a network cable. The network cable has been verified as functional with another computer.
- In Network Connections, the status is "Network cable unplugged" even when the cable is plugged in.
- When I remove the cable, it claims that it is safe to remove the "Broadcom NetLink (TM) Gigabit Ethernet". (Which is on the motherboard.)
- The WiFi is still working (thank goodness!)

I suspect this might have been caused by new drivers and support that was automatically installed when someone plugged in a cordless mouse USB adapter and then removed it without requesting Windows XP to deactivate it.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest disabling/uninstalling it in Device Manager, then grab (& install) the updated [Chipset](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=uk&prodNameId=3687780&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=3687777&swLang=13&taskId=135&swEnvOID=1093#11394) and [USB](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=uk&prodNameId=3687780&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=3687777&swLang=13&taskId=135&swEnvOID=1093#11395) drivers from the HP website followed by a reboot.

Next troubleshooting would be disabling it in the BIOS or even 'rolling back' the driver to the original HP ones (or even reinstalling them from your HP support CD's)

Comment: That would probably be a good approach, but I think the actual hardware has failed. Engineer due today some time so I'll let you know.

Comment: Goodluck! Let us know the outcome! :)

Comment: The engineer had my laptop in a thousand pieces to replace the motherboard. Seems to be working fine now. I'll mark this as the answer to close this question.

Comment: Thanks! Glad to hear it was resolved, definately a hardware failure - hope it was under warranty! :)